# problems with plupload being blocked

Tags: plupload

I'm having issues with control plupload uploading files for a client.  On this one client's computer it's being blocked somehow.  They are receiving a -400 security error.  The cross domain policy is fine.  Hasn't changed in a long time and others are using it. Is there a particular port that flash needs open that may be blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing that domain directly from that computer?
There may be an unrelated issue causing plupload not to find the crossdomain.xml on that server (firewall, hostfile, etc). Try accessing that domain from the browser and see what errors, if any, you get.

If the other domain is accessible, try clearing the cache on the client computer in question (if they ok it, some people are twitchy on this for some reason), and reload your apps site, to see if some old configuration/js/whatever file is hanging around in the cache.

Comment: I don't have access to this client's computer. If I have them access the client access policy file or cross domain policy file from the browser address bar is that really equivalent to a call from within my website page's domain.  I guess it just would show it was blocked or not.

Comment: Although your page is served from your domain, the cross domain action is taking place on the client computer. Your server isn't parsing the page or the control the client is. Checking accessibility from the client lets you know if there is a specific error related to accessing that file from the client, and may give you insight into what is causing the inaccessibility. Specific HTTP error codes are always easier to work with than, 'it just isn't working', or the non-helpful -400 security error that plupload is giving you.